# When attempting to utilize the POST method in routes, I'm encountering an issue where the Request Body is returning as undefined

Tags: next.js, fetch, http-post, app-router

I am encountering difficulty in posting my data to a JSON file (data-dummy.json). Additionally, when attempting to debug by logging the request.body to the console, I am receiving an undefined value. While data is successfully transmitted to the client-side, it fails to reach the API routes properly. Only the date is being appended to the JSON file. It's worth noting that I am utilizing the App Router rather than the File Router.

```
//form-data.js 

"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Textarea } from "../ui/textarea";
import { useRef } from "react";

export function FormData() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const feedbackRef = useRef();

  const handleFeedbackButton = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Handling feedback submission...");
    const emailEntered = emailRef.current.value;
    const feedbackEntered = feedbackRef.current.value;

    const reqBody = { email: emailEntered, text: feedbackEntered };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(reqBody), 
      });
      console.log(reqBody);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting feedback:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Card className="w-[350px]">
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Feedback Form</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>Your feedback makes us grow bigger</CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <form action="POST" onSubmit={handleFeedbackButton}>
          <div className="grid w-full items-center gap-4">
            <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1.5">
              <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
              <Input
                id="email"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Your email"
                ref={emailRef}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1.5">
              <Label htmlFor="text">Feedback</Label>
              <Textarea
                id="text"
                type="text"
                name="text"
                placeholder="Enter your feedback here"
                ref={feedbackRef}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <CardFooter className="flex items-center gap-10 mt-10 ml-[-20px]">
            <Button variant="outline">Close</Button>
            <Button type="submit">Submit your Feedback</Button>{" "}
          </CardFooter>
        </form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

```
api/route.js

import { writeFile, readFile } from "fs/promises"; // Importing specific functions from fs/promises

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    // Extracting email and text from the request body
    const { email, text } = request.body;

    // Logging the request body for debugging
    console.log("Request Body:", email);

    // Creating a new feedback object with an ID and the provided email and text
    const newFeedback = {
      id: new Date().toISOString(),
      email,
      text,
    };

    // Reading the existing data from the JSON file
    const fileData = await readFile(
      process.cwd() + "/data/data-dummy.json",
      "utf8"
    );
    const data = JSON.parse(fileData);

    // Appending the new feedback to the existing data
    data.push(newFeedback);

    // Writing the updated data back to the JSON file
    await writeFile(
      process.cwd() + "/data/data-dummy.json",
      JSON.stringify(data)
    );

    // Returning a success response with the updated feedback
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "OK SUCCESS", feedback: newFeedback }),
      {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Handling errors and returning an error response
    console.error("Error writing to file:", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({
        message: "Error writing to file",
        error: error.message,
      }),
      {
        status: 500,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```
data-dummy.json 

[{"id":"2024-01-25T16:17:37.223Z"}] // this is all i am getting while posting
```